# Version Control for Local Website (XAMPP)

Tags: version-control, localhost

I am working on a shopping cart which is installed locally via xampp.

The files are stored in:

D:/xampp/htdocs/cart

Now I would like to start making coding changes and design changes, but I need to keep a track of what changes i make so that I can go back and forth.

I would like to mention that I am the only developer working on the code, so i dont need any online repository. Everything is setup locally on my home computer.

how can I go that ?

**UPDATE:**
After testing Subversion and Mercurial, i finally went with Mercurial and TortoiseHg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that installing mercurial and using tortoisehg has been a really easy solution for me. Tortoise pretty much walks you through everything, holding your hand the whole way. Makes it very simple.

Comment: Ill test out both TortoiseHg and TortoiseSVN

Answer (score 5):

Depends on your needs, but for a single user project you probably will be happy with [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads) for Windows. It comes with shell integration and is relatively easy to use.

Comment: Isn't TortoiseSVN just a client?

Comment: I think the install routine is not much of a challenge. Maybe you need some reboot, although the setup bugs me every time I don't need those. Just create somewhere a directory for example on a backup drive call it CartSVN or whatever you like. Right click -> TortoiseSVN -> Create repository here. Now you have a repository. Go to "D:/xampp/htdocs/cart" right click -> SVN Checkout and choose the CartSVN directory. You are done! Now you only need to commit your changes on a daily basis... (btw. the hidden .svn directories are needed!)

Comment: Thanks for explaining the steps. Ill try it right now and get back.

Comment: I installed TortoiseSVN, but when i tried to Checkout, it did not give a option for selecting a local directory for CHeckout. it asked for URL. So i uninstalled it and installed TortoiseHg, its working fine till now.

Comment: "file:///C:/somewhere/backup/CartSVN" probably would have been the right URL. However I'm glad you are now satisfied with TortoiseHG.

Comment: It did not even give an option for Browsing for a local file. 

But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git without a central server to make changes locally and keep track of them.
I've used it successfully when I was blocked by firewall rules from accessing a source control server.  Of course you run the risk of the machine failing and having no backups!

Comment: All my files are stored locally, and I am the only one working on the code. 

How should I proceed ? Which system should I install and setup ? Any tutorials ?

Answer (score 0):

Use subversion. Easiest is to install Visual SVN for the server side, and then add your website's directory to source control using TortoiseSVN for the client side.

Comment: Is VisualSVN free ?  So I need to install both VSN and TSVN ?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you really don't want to use an online repo, you'll need to install a version control server. There are many options, including [Apache Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) and [CVS](http://www.nongnu.org/cvs/). Once you've configured that, you'll need to download a client that supports whatever server you're using.